# How to show Floating Window for Sign with Google Plus in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have to implement signin with facebook and google plus in my android application.Successfully implemented facebook as like the below image.[image]

But when i implement sign in with Google plus it shows like [Google plus image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aad4b.jpg)

Please someone help me to implement the same like the Facebook Login for sign in with Google plus in android. So that user can enter whatever gmail account he prefer to sign in to Google.

Comment: g+ shows like that just because you don't have a plus profile setup with that account, otherwise it would show directly the permission screen, it uses a dialog (or a dialogFragment?) anyway. FB uses the webview approach when the mobile app is not instaled on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [SocialAuth](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/) library, which supports many social networks, including `Facebook` and `Google+`.

*Note:* Can provide code examples how to login in corresponding social networks using this library (Facebook, Google+) later, if needed.

**Update:**

1) client id's are stored in `oauth_consumer.properties` file (put it in `assets` folder)

```
#facebook
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key = YOUR_KEY
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = YOUR_SECRET

#Google Plus
googleapis.com.consumer_key=YOUR_KEY.apps.googleusercontent.com
googleapis.com.consumer_secret=YOUR_SECRET
```

2) `Google+` requires redirect url. Specify redirect url in google console of the project and add it in `SocialAdapter` during initialization.

```
...
socialAuthAdapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener(), null);
setAuthProviders();
...

private void setAuthProviders() {
    socialAuthAdapter.addProvider(SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facbook);
    socialAuthAdapter.addProvider(SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, R.drawable.google);
    socialAuthAdapter.addCallBack(SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, GOOGLE_PLUS_CALLBACK_URL); 
    //urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob - if you set this url, than accessToken received from social network should be handled manually (web page (in WebView) with login response from Google+ will contain in header or in response link accessToken, and you will get it manually by parsing that links). not the best way.
    socialAuthAdapter.enable(social);
}
```

3) You will get accessToken in `ResponseListener` when login flow will be finished:

```
private class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle bundle) {
        final String providerName = bundle.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);
        SocialNetwork network = SocialNetwork.valueOf(providerName);

        String accessToken = socialAuthAdapter.getCurrentProvider().getAccessGrant().getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final SocialAuthError socialAuthError) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
    }
}
```

You can read more about redirect url [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp), in *"Forming the URL for an authentication request"* section.

Comment: Hey dude,You link supports me lot but can you please tell me how to change the client id and redirect uri in library file.